# No value given for one or more required parameters when Changing DropDownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Totally two drop downs

Getting values from database like:

**Drop DOWN 1(Products)**

- Ice Cream
- Chocolates
- Cool Drinks

if from first drop down list 1 selected  Ice cream it will display

**Drop Down 2(varieties)**

- Vanilla
- Strawberry
- Mango

if from first drop down list 1 selected  Chocolates it will display

**Drop Down 2(varieties)**

- Dark chocolate
- Milk Chocolate
- Caramel Chocolate

Other items should clear and displays the above only

---

### Code Used

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txtval = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    string txtval1 = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

    string str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\123\\WebSite1\\Checking_Db.mdb";
    OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection(str);
    db.Open();                                    
    //  string st = "select Emp_Ph_No from emp where Emp_Name =  DropDownList1.SelectedValue ;";

    string st = "select Emp_Ph_No from emp where Emp_Name = txtval1;";

    OleDbCommand dbc = new OleDbCommand(st, db);
    OleDbDataReader read = dbc.ExecuteReader();

    DropDownList2.DataSource = read;
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "variety";       
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = ""variety";       
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    read.Close();
    db.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* this code is resulting in that error?  I don't see any actual parameters in your SQL, but I do see a syntax error where you try to use a C# variable in your string.

Comment: if i use like this means  string st = "select Emp_Ph_No from emp where Emp_Name =  DropDownList1.SelectedValue ;";

Comment: That's still a syntax error.  You can't use variables in strings like that.  (Nor should you for SQL statements, that would be a SQL injection vulnerability.)  Soner's answer below shows how you would add a value to a SQL statement.

Comment: checked through breakpoint Getting txtval =2 and txtval 1= Ice Cream but it produces an error

Comment: I'm not sure how else to describe this.  You're *fundamentally* misunderstanding how C# and SQL work.  Honestly, I recommend walking through some introductory tutorials on the subject.

Comment: sorry , ya sure new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem on that line;

```
...where Emp_Name = txtval1;
```

If `txtval1` is a `string`, you would use it as `Emp_Name = 'txtval1'`. This is not a valid syntax. In that case, OLEDB provider thinks this `txtval1` is a parameter and you didn't suplied any value for that.

You can set this value as a parameter and add to your command like;

```
string st = "select Emp_Ph_No from emp where Emp_Name = ?";
OleDbCommand dbc = new OleDbCommand(st, db);
dbc.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtval1);
```

I used `AddWithValue` in my example but **you don't**. [This method *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` overloads to specify your parameter `OleDbType` and it's size.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically instead of callind `.Close` or `.Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var db = new OleDbConnection(str))
using(var dbc = db.CreateCommand)
{
    // Set your CommandText.
    // Add your parameter value.

    using(var read = dbc.ExecuteReader())
    {
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: Working !! Thanks for your help. modified with .Add() new to this language very very thanks Great!